# How to tweak left div border

Tags: html, css

please I want make a div that has left border with 2 different px sizes. What I mean here is, I want the left border to be 1px but has a thick width of 5px starts after about 1cm from top and ends before about 1 cm of the end.

Something like the done column of this photo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M345T.png)

Using only the `div {border-left: 5px;}` will increase the width of the entire left-border like this image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUCLR.png) and it's not what I want.

Comment: Can you add what you tried so far and also add some visual indication in the image on what you require

Comment: I just updated my post with 2 different images

Comment: the only way to get a border that isn't full length is to absolutely position a pseudo element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to specify different values for each border of the div

Use `border-position: width-value style color` for example to apply for the left border use `border-left: 2px solid #000000` and the same for `border-right`, `border-top`, `border-bottom` if you need

**this is edited:
I tried to create something similar to your needs.

```css
.parent{
   margin: 50px auto;
   width: 350px;
   border: 1px solid #eee;
   border-top: 20px solid #eee;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

.child1{
   text-align: center;
}

.child2{
   border-left: 10px solid #000;
   margin-left: -5px;
}

.child2 h3{margin-left: 20px;}

.box{
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #eee;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin: 30px 20px;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child1">
      <h3>Done</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="child2">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <div class="box">
         <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
         <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
         </p>
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

you can also review it in codepen [here](https://codepen.io/DohaHelmy/pen/KKwNEPp)

Comment: Thank you. 

I understand that my post is very confusing, so I just updated it with two different images of what I have and what I want to achieve .

Comment: @Ros4eva please read my answer again. I tried to make a solution for your needs. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much dear! You're the real genius!

Comment: @Ros4eva you're welcome ^^

Answer (score 1):

Simply nest a new div with position absolute. Give it a height and use top and bottom to position it as you need.